# KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access from SparkStreaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I have set up multiple streams reading from different kafka topics:

```
for(topic <- topics) {

  val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
    ssc,
    PreferConsistent, 
    Subscribe[String, String](
      Array(topicConfig.srcTopic),
      kafkaParameters()
    )
  )
  stream.map(...).reduce(...)...
}
```

kafkaParameters basically has the needed config:

```
  "bootstrap.servers" -> bootstrapServers,
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> groupId,
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)//,
```

I am using kafka 0.10 integration with spark streaming. The spark configuration is:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("AppName").set("spark.streaming.concurrentJobs", "4")
```

And getting the exception:

```
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.acquire(KafkaConsumer.java:1625)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.seek(KafkaConsumer.java:1198)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.seek(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:95)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:69)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:228)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.next(KafkaRDD.scala:194)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:393)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1336)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1353)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1353)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
... 3 more
```

Comment: Why are you opening multiple streams? That kind of defeats the purpose of the direct streaming approach.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov cuz I need to process several streams (from one topic to another, doing some transformation). And for that I have an app level cache they are accessing, so for the cache to be shared the streams are in the same job.

Comment: But the direct streaming approach already allows you to consume multiple topics in a distributed fashion. You don't need multiple streams.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes because I need to send back to a destination topic depending on the origin topic so it would be something like:

src A ---> dst A
srcB ---> dst B

If I consume puttin all topics in the same array, it wouldnt be like taht they would be aggregated right?

Comment: No, you can still group them by topic name, you get that information from Kafka.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov could you point me somehow to documentation? I did not manage to find it. Thanks!

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Maybe you are refering to using a message handler, but there is no support to that on kafka010 as far I got to see

Comment: Solved with a different approach, using: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813846/messagehandler-in-kafkautils010-sparkstreaming/42817214#42817214