# spark-streaming-kafka-0-10: KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access

Tags: spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I am trying to move from spark-streaming-kafka-0.8 to spark-streaming-kafka-0.10 and I faced the following error:
**KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access**

We have multiple kafka clusters in different DCs that I want to consume simultaneously in Scala Spark Streaming application.
In version 0.8 it has worked properly - we've just called createDirectStream multiple times, once for each cluster. But after upgrading to 0.10 it stopped working.

The only relevant answer I found is here: [KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access from SparkStreaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762020/kafkaconsumer-is-not-safe-for-multi-threaded-access-from-sparkstreaming)
, but it is related to consuming multiple topics from the same cluster. Currently it is impossible to specify multiple clusters in a single call to createDirectStream and at the same time calling it multiple times leads to an error.

My question is: is there any way to consume data with spark-streaming-kafka-0.10 from multiple clusters?